# Possible OpenGL ES 2.0 threading issue

Tags: c++, opengl-es

Hi I am trying to make a game engine and I have a problem when I try to render 
two quads at the same time. One of them starts blinking and the other doesn't. But if I add only one quad on the screen doesn't blink.

I have changed the emulator but makes the same and I think is because I have no threads implemented.

I'm right or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, it doesn't have anything to do with threads. In fact you should not try to move the two quads with two different threads.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely a result of the depth buffer.  The pixels of the rendering are usually given a certain depth value 0..255. If the items are close enough these values will be the same and 'z-fighting' will occur. OpenGL is not multi-threaded. The closest OpenGL gets to having timing related issues is when using tile-defered rendering.